# C++ - Code crashes when trying to sort 2d vector

Tags: c++

I'm writing a code in C++ and it's always giving the same error: Segmentation Fault, but I don't know why this is happening. I've created a small program that gives the error.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int N = 17;
vector<vector<int>> v;
void func(vector<int>& x){
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        v.push_back(vector<int>(x));
    }
}

int main(){

    int n = 5;
    vector<int> v2(n, 0);
    func(v2);
    cout << v.size() << endl; // prints 17

    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [&n](const auto &a, const auto &b){
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if(a[i] != b[i]) return a[i] < b[i]; 
        return true;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

The function `func` is supposed to do a recursive computation. I pass `v2` by reference because I push and pop elements from it. When I got to a certain point in recursion, I add it to the global 2d vector `v`.

My code's working to every test case I tried except this one.

The fun thing is that the programs works with no error when N < 17.

The error is happening at the lambda sort. There is an 'a' that breaks the code. Even if erase the for loop, it still crashes.

I know that using global variable is bad, but in competitive programming this is a common practice.

I'm compiling with the following:

> g++ test.cpp && ./a.out

My g++ version:

> (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @DrewDormann, I managed to fix it.

Just changing the return of the lambda function to false instead of true.

Comment: Have you tried running this with a debugger or ASan? (for ASan, using compiler flags `-Og -g -fsanitize=address` may show more insightful error messages)

Comment: `std::sort` sort comparator should compare two arbitratry container items which are given as `a` and `b`, yours is completely wrong

Comment: `std::sort` with a comparison predicate requires that `comp(a,b)` and `comp(b,a)` must never both return `true`.  That is, it can not report that `a` must be before `b` and `b` must be before `a`.  The `return true;` in your lambda violates this requirement.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I've edited the question.

Comment: Consider using `std::lexicographical_compare` to implement your comparison function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::sort` requires irreflexivity. From **[alg.sorting]** in the standard:

> The term *strict* refers to the requirement of an irreflexive relation (`!comp(x, x)` for all `x`)

However, the lambda returns `true` for `comp(x, x)`.

---

> The fun thing is that the programs works with no error when N < 17.

It's undefined behavior. It's unlucky if it works by chance.